# Dlib Error: error C1083: Cannot open include file:'type_safe_union/type_safe_union_kernel.h'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, dlib

I'd like to use the image processing package of Dlib (C++ library) in Visual Studio 2013.

I created an empty project and added "dlib-18.16\dlib\all\source.cpp" to my Source Files in the Solution Explorer. Then, I added the path to dlib-18.16 to my Include Directories in VC++ Directories and I also added the path to dlib-18.16\dlib to my Additional Include Directories in C/C++ General of Visual Studio.

I can run the file matrix_ex.cpp which is one of the examples of Dlib, but I can't run the file face_detection_ex.cpp because of the error " Cannot open include file:'type_safe_union/type_safe_union_kernel.h' " which is actually caused by the line `#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>`

How can I resolve this issue? Why the program finds some header files but it can't find the others while they are all located in the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dlib folder itself to the Include Directories in VC++ Directories, you instead added the folder above it.

By extension that would mean your include directive needs to be `#include <image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>`.

Let me list a hypothetical example to explain better. You downloaded `dlib-18.16.tar.bz2` and extracted it to `c:\projects`. This creates a folder named `c:\projects\dlib-18.16`. Within VC++ Directories you added `c:\projects\dlib-18.16` to the Include Directories.

However this isn't correct, you should remove that directory and instead add `c:\projects\dlib-18.16\dlib` as that is the include directory for the project.

That will cause `#include <type_safe_union/type_safe_union_kernel.h>` to load `C:\projects\dlib-18.16\dlib\type_safe_union\type_safe_union_kernel.h` as well as similar internal links between files.

Comment: I did that and it got worse. Now, it can't find ` #include <matrix.h> ` or ` #include <matrix/matrix.h> ` either.

Comment: @user3504976: Expanded to include real folders to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense and I followed your instructions but it is not working. Probably, the error is caused by something else. Is adding ...\dlib-18.16\dlib to include directory the only required step to use Dlib in visual studio?

Comment: @user3504976: Try adding the absolute path.